# If $f$ is continuous on $2$ subsets, is it also continuous on the union?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Sorry if this has been asked already, my searches on continuity for the union of two sets just gets me results for uniform continuity.

$(M,d)$ is a metric space. Let $f:M\to\Bbb R$ and let $A\subset M$ and $B\subset M$.  If $f$ is continuous at every point in $A$ and at every point in $B$, then is $f$ continuous at  every point of $A\cup B$?
Now I would say yes, $A\cup B$ consists of {$x$: $x\in A$ or $x\in B$}
And since $f$ is continuous at every point in $A$ and every point in $B$.

Any help/guidance or anything else is appreciated.

Comment: maybe you need that $A\cap B$ is non empty

Comment: It need not be continuous. I'd post an answer but I'm on a cell phone. Let $A=(0,1)$ and $B=[1,2)$ and find two functions that make this fail.

Comment: There is a problem with the way this is being formulated. If it is continuous at every point of $A$ and at every point of $B$ then it is continuous at every point of the union, as you say. The counterexamples given say that it's not true that if the restrictions of a function to two subsets are continuous then the function with domain the union is continuous. There are two different statements.

Comment: @MattSamuel - If you have time in your schedule today: would you mind writing a convincing argument to this problem? I am not convinced by the argument given below and believe you could shed some light on this.

Comment: @TaylorRendon you just didn't understand the solution below. there's nothing wrong with it

Comment: @mathworker21 I'm sure there is nothing wrong with it, but you are correct that I do not understand it. With that said, I started this bounty to give more detail to the answer below so people, such as myself, who are new to metric spaces and possibly (graduate, in my case) analysis can have a little more clarity.

Comment: @TaylorRendon Yea, that's fine; I was just objecting to your use of the word "convincing". Like, you can't call Andrew Wiles's proof of Fermat's Last Theorem not convincing just because you don't understand it.

Comment: @mathworker21 - haha, that was actually pretty funny! Very true. I should not have used the word "convincing". I am excited to see however, what light can be shed to undo my misunderstanding of the given answer.

Comment: @Taylor Unfortunately I don't think I can shed any additional light beyond what is already there. It is very similar to what my answer would be. The function is readily seen to be continuous on those two subsets, but if you look at the left and right hand limits at $1$, they're different. So it's not continuous on the union.

Comment: @TaylorRendon "undo my misunderstanding"?? So you misunderstand it rather than not understand it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define the function $f: (0,2) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}x& & x\in(0,1)\\ x+1& & x\in[1,2)\end{array}\right.$$

This $f$ is continuous on $A=(0,1)$ and $B=[1,2)$ but not on $A\cup B$.

However, if $A$ and $B$ are either both open or both closed and the function value agrees on their intersection then $f$ will be continuous.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, and providing and example I can relate to! I think I can finish it now.  I can construct a sequence in A$\cup$B that will not have a limit.

Comment: @R_D - why is the function not continuous on $A \cup B$?

Comment: One way to say it is the left hand limit is $\lim_{x^-\to1}f(x)=\lim_{h\to0}f(1-h)=\lim_{h\to0}(1-h)=1$ but the right hand limit is $\lim_{x^+\to1}f(x)=\lim_{h\to0}f(1+h)=\lim_{h\to0}(1+h+1)=2$. Since the 2 are not equal the function is not continuous at $x=1$.

Answer (score 3):

Language abiguities may be causing confusion here. The assumption "$f$ is continuous at each point of $A$" can  mean that if $x\in A$ and $\epsilon>0,$ then there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $y\in M$ and $d(y,x)<\delta,$ then $|f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon.$ Same thing for "$f$ is continuous at each point of $B.$" If this is the understanding, then it is obvious that $f$ is continuous at each point of $A\cup B.$

But sometimes "$f$ is continuous at each point of $A,$" might be shortened to "$f$ is continuous on $A$". However, the latter often means $f|_A$ is continuous with respect to the metric space $A.$ That is a different thing. So if we have $f$ continuous on $A$ and on $B,$ with this understanding, then it is certainly possible that $f$ is not continuous on $A\cup B,$ meaning $f|_{A\cup B}$ is not continuous with respect to the metric space $A\cup B.$ The older answer shows this.

Given that, the first order of business should be to understand precisely the mathematics of the situation. What are the precise definitions, assumptions, and conclusions in play here?

Comment: This is very insightful. Thank you for your response. I think my confusion lies, truly, here: Why would the corrections at the bottom of the answer (given by R_D) make the function continuous on $A \cup B$? "if $A$ and $B$ are either both open or both closed and the function value agrees on their intersection then $f$ will be continuous on the union".

Comment: OK, happy to look at this, but ... What definition of "continuous on the union" are you using?

Comment: Well, i'm assuming a map $f$ is continuous at each point in the union of two sets $A \cup B$ $\iff$ $f$ is continuous at each point of $A$ and $B$. But, not having known there was a continuity definition for the *union* of two sets might be the source of my confusion... please do explain though.

Comment: Continuous with respect to which metric space?

Comment: Well in this question, the metric space $M$ is arbitrary. So, with that in mind i'm guessing the definition I am referring to is an arbitrary metric space $(M,d)$.