# If $A,B$ are both closed (or both open) and $f_{|A}, f_{|B}$ are continuous, then so is $f_{|A \cup B}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ be a topological space and $f:X \to \mathbb R$. Let $A,B$ be non-empty subsets of $X$ such that $f_{|A}, f_{|B}$ are continuous. Let $C := A \cup B$. I'm trying to prove a statement mention in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1493275/1019043), i.e.,

> **Theorem:** If $A, B$ are both closed or both open, then $f_{|C}$ is continuous.

Could you have a check on my below attempt?

**My attempt:**  WLOG, we assume $A, B$ are both closed. Let $F$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb R$. We have $A \cap f^{-1} (F)$ is closed in $A$, so there is $A'$ closed in $X$ such that $A \cap f^{-1} (F) = A' \cap A$. Similarly, there is $B'$ closed in $X$ such that $B \cap f^{-1} (F) = B' \cap B$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
C \cap f^{-1} (F) &= (A \cap f^{-1} (F)) \cup (B \cap f^{-1} (F)) \\
&= (A' \cap A) \cup (B' \cap B) \\
&= (A' \cup B') \cap  (A' \cup B) \cap  (A \cup B') \cap  (A \cup B).
\end{align}
$$

Notice that $(A' \cup B'), (A' \cup B),  (A \cup B')$ are closed in $X$, so $C \cap f^{-1} (F)$ is closed in $C = A \cup B$. The claim then follows.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Also note there's nothing in this that is particular to the topology of $\mathbb{R}$, so it holds for a general topological co-domain as well