# C^2 in the interior, C^2 on the boundary, what about the continuity over the closure?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $ B_R = B(0,R) $ be the open ball of radius R centered at $0$. Suppose the function $g \in C^2(B_R)$ and $ g=f$ on the boundary $ \partial B_R$ where $f \in C^2(R^n)$. Can we conclude that $g$ is continuous on $\overline B_R$ ?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: [This duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1493275) gave a counterexample (up to translation of the center of the ball).

Comment: @AnneBauval I asked about what my intuition said while I was confused, this was not an exercise of sorts and I didn't ask for a solution. It was just a tiny part of a way bigger PDE problem I was solving and I needed advice. Downvoting my question shows a lot about your ethics. You could just redirect me to the answer you refer as a duplicate, and I would close my question, end of story, no big deal. But instead you decided to downvote me, thanks!

Comment: Though you did not answer PC1's comment, I provided a link. Usually, for such "no context" questions, we don't, so your thanks are welcome. Note that you could not close your question. We did.

Comment: P.S. I also often upvote questions. I would have been glad to upvote yours if you enriched it with some thoughts or attempts.

Comment: @AnneBauval Didn't have the chance to answer PC1's comment, as the question was already answered BEFORE PC1 commented, with a counter example by Maximilian Simon. Sorry for not being active 24/7 on stackexchange. I would gladly answer to PC1 if it was an earlier comment than the answer given, but this was not the case. And by "closing" the question, I meant deleting it. Keep your salty comments for yourself, and away from this community. Your high reputation does not agree with your manners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $g(x):=\chi_{B_R}(x)$ (indicator of $B_R$) meets the requirements with $f\equiv0$ but is not continous on the closure of $B_R$.

Comment: That sounds right. Thank you.

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.